# Nginx and GeoLite2 not working

Tags: nginx, geoip

Is Nginx official `ngx_mod_http_geoip` compatible with GeoLite2 databases ? I can't get them working, so I assume they are not compatible ?

Answer (score 4):

`ngx_mod_http_geoip` is not compatible with GeoIP2 databases; you will need the [ngx_http_geoip2_module](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module) instead.  Note, however, that as of this writing the `nginx` distribution packages I'm aware of don't include the `ngx_http_geoip2_module` and you will need to compile NGINX from source and include `ngx_http_geoip2_module`.  See [these instructions](https://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/geoip2-and-nginx/) for an example of building this for Ubuntu.

Disclaimer:  I wrote these instructions.

Answer (score 4):

I found this site https://www.miyuru.lk/geoiplegacy which has recent datasets in DAT format converted from newer database formats.

These are compatible with the older nginx geoip module. 
So no need to build the geoip2 module from source.

Comment: Country works great. City not. Anyway: THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

The official module is called ngx_http_geoip_module and according to the documentation, requires the MaxMind GeoIP library.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html

Given the official documentation, yes, you can assume they are not compatible, and that you really need the required one instead.

Answer (score -1):

> **Official way**

[This video link to install GeoIP with  GeoLite2 databases](https://youtu.be/gG842QJiGkI)

Comment: Please don't link youtube videos like this, instead try to write your answers.